# Vuejs showing raw syntax within code and not rendering content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a shopping cart app made of 3 pages. pages are shown/hidden using css based on which part of the process they have completed.

For the first 2 pages, vue works perfect, i can even use vue dev tools to see all of my data. But once I get to the 3rd page vue stops, it shows raw content such as in this screenshot - https://share.getcloudapp.com/2NujBEmb

Once I get to the 3rd page, taking a look at vue tools, I can see this exact same data is not null but instead filled out correctly with data as expected. Just not rendering to the page.

Has anyone ever ran into an issue simlar to this? I have so far tried using a separate cdn, checking for broken tags and wrongly named tags but everything seems fine.

Here is a small snippet of the delivery address code incase I am missing something

```
<div class="review-details">
            <p class="sc-back-text" v-on:click="nextPrev(-1)"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>BACK TO EDIT ORDER</p>
            <h2 class="red-text section-title">Review Details</h2>
            <p><b>First Name:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.firstName }}</p>
            <p><b>Last Name:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.lastName }}</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.email }}</p>
            <p><b>Company Name:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.companyName }}</p>
            <p><b>Job Title:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.jobTitle }}</p>
            <p><b>Address 1:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.address1 }}</p>
            <p><b>Address 2:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.address2 }}</p>
            <div class="review-details-split">
                <div class="review-details-1">
                    <p><b>City:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.city }}</p>
                    <p><b>Country:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.country }}</p>
                    <p v-if="countryIsUSA"><b>State:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.state }}</p>
                    <p v-if="countryIsCAN"><b>Province:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.province }}</p>
                    <p v-if="countryIsREGION"><b>Region:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.region }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="review-details-2">
                    <p><b>Zip Code:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.zipCode }}</p>
                    <p><b>Phone Number:</b> {{ deliveryAddress.phoneNumber }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I see your screenshot and I can see that you have added Quote ( " ) to wrap variable. so use it without Quote ( " )
i.e. use {{ deliveryAddress.email }} instead of "{{ deliveryAddress.email }}"

Comment: can you also add your script please ?

Comment: @PunitPatel I noticed that as well, but you can see in the code snippet that im not actually using quotes. Im not sure why its rendering with quotes

Comment: @JaySnel Could you please provide some code snippet?

Comment: @tawfiknasser unfortunately this is for a company and the script is rather large along with using api's to actually render some of the data even shown in the first place. I know this is not ideal at all but not really sure how else to seek out help.

Comment: @PunitPatel take a look above

Comment: @JaySnel So I am not sure what other code you have but I share you component structure that you could compare your one.
`<template>

</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "test"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>`
Your HTML code should be under <template></template> tag

Comment: @PunitPatel thank you! My issue was that in migrating the app, I didnt have this section inside of the main #app div tag. Your solution to look at template tags lead me to this and I am good to go now